# Profiling depositado no Repositório de Versionamento(GitHub)

Tags: git, github, gcc

Estou fazendo alguns testes com um código experimental que faz contagem de ciclistas na ciclofaixa, para estes testes estou usando o `gprof` e `gcov` que geram diversos arquivos de análise, um destes aquivos gerado pelo `gprof` estou enviando para o repositório de versionamento para manter um histórico relativo a melhoria do código.

Os demais arquivos devo enviar também? Qual estrutura de arquivos devo usar para tal histórico de optimização e relatórios de profiling.

Answer (score 2):

Delfino,

Via de regra, o normal não é você colocar dados coletados de um build, por exemplo, ou de resultados de teste; no controle de versão. 
Normalmente esse tipo de dado entra em banco de dados OLAP, ou como input de um ferramenta. 
Eu não conheço esses tipos de arquivos, porém, imagino que você irá usar alguma ferramenta para ler esses dados, se ela irá pegar do controle de versão, seria interessante criar um novo repositório somente para esses dados, ou irá onerar o repositório de código, fazendo que os desenvolvedores baixem arquivos desnecessários ao desenvolvimento e de tamanho grande. Se a fonte para a análise não for nem o repositório git, esse arquivo não deve ser colocado lá. Seria uma má prática.

Comment: o arquivo é um txt comum com diversas anotações, os arquivos raw não penso em colocar são realmente binários e gerados localmente, apesar que podem ser unificados para uma analise posterior. Pensei em colocar como submódulo, mas cai na mesma questão de ter material em excesso para baixar, um banco de dados remoto não é viável, e uma ferramenta de compartilhamento de arquivos como dropbox não sei se resolveria pois não iria controlar bem múltiplos usuários atualizando os mesmos arquivos.

Comment: Por que um banco de dados remoto não é viável? Ou mesmo um local, sendo sincronizado manualmente

Comment: Eu não tenho o banco de dados, e o arquivo não passa de um arquivo TXT, e o uso de cloud não dá abertura para que todos alterem com versionamento os arquivos, Sugestões são bem vindas.